# sql error : ORA-02291: integrity constraint (MHVU.WORKS_ON_FK) violated - parent key not found

Tags: sql, oracle

i have this table
with essn = int , pno = int, hours = decimal(5,2) with essn and pno are primary keys, and when i tried to insert values, this error occurrs

[image]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Unrelated, but: numbers are specified **without** single quotes in SQL. `'1'` is string constant. `1` is a number

Answer (score 0):

ORA-02291: integrity constraint (string.string) violated - parent key not found

Cause: A foreign key value has no matching primary key value.

Action: Delete the foreign key or add a matching primary key.

For an insert statement, this ORA-02291 error is common when you are trying to insert a child without a matching parent, as defined by a foreign key constraint.  In that case, you need to add the parent row to the table and then re-insert your child table row.